# Formulario de login con AJAX y PHP

Tags: php, ajax

tengo un problema con un formulario de login que estoy haciendo con php y ajax.
El archivo en Php hace la consulta a la base de datos para que el sistema sepa si existe o no el usuario y saber si los datos son correctos:

```
//Datos de acceso
$email=strtolower($_GET['email']);
$pass=md5($_GET['password']);


//consulta para sacar el usuario y contraseña de la bbdd
$consulta="SELECT IdUsuario, Email, Password FROM Usuarios WHERE Email='".$email."'";

$resultado = mysqli_query($con, $consulta);
$datos = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado);

    //guardamos los resultados de la consulta
    $emailBBDD=$datos['Email'];
    $passBBDD=$datos['Password'];



//Comprobamos si los datos son correctos
if(($emailBBDD == $email) && ($pass==$passBBDD)){
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['IdUsuario']=$datos['IdUsuario'];
    $_SESSION['estado']='Autenticado';
    echo '
        <script>
            window.location="../users/index.php";
        </script>
    ';
}   
else{
    echo '
        <script>
            $(#mensaje).html("Error al hacer el login");
        </script>
        ';
}
```

Y por otro lado el AJAX que envia los datos al php y... ahora viene mi pregunta, no sé que tipo de error me está dando que no me va el login y se recarga la página sin motivo aparente. Estoy empezando con AJAX, así que agradezco cualquier corrección que me hagáis en el código:

```
              $("#submit").click(function() {
                    //alert("yes");

                    //recogemos los datos del formulario
                    var email = $("input#email").val();
                    var password = $("input#password").val();

                    var dataString = 'email='+email+'&password='+password;

                    //alert(dataString);
                //Llamamos a la función AJAX de jQuery
                    $.ajax({                        
                        url: "includes/login.php",                      
                        type: "GET",                        

                        data: dataString,                       

                        success: function(response) {
                            $('#mensaje').html(response);

                        }

                });

            });
```

Muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Hola muy buenas tardes saludos desde Perú. Me fascina que seas sincero. Primero lo primero en el PHP debes devolver un JSON.

```
if(($emailBBDD == $email) && ($pass==$passBBDD)){
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['IdUsuario']=$datos['IdUsuario'];
  $_SESSION['estado']='Autenticado';
  echo json_encode(array('message' => 'success', 'scrip: ' => '
      <script>
          window.location="../users/index.php";
      </script>
       '));
}   
// Igual manera en el else






     $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'includes/login.php',
        data: {
            'email': $('input:text[name=email]').val(),
            // o accediendo por su id "#email" u class ".boton1"
            'password': $('input:text[name=password]').val()
        },
        success: function (data) {
            // Materialize.toast(data.message, 4000);
            $('#mensaje').html(data.script);
        },
        // con esta funcion puedes ver un error mas profundo
        error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
            var msg = '';
            if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                msg = 'Not connect.\n Verify Network.';
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 401) {
                msg = "Necesita loguearse";
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                msg = 'Requested page not found. [404]';
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                msg = 'Internal Server Error [500].';
            } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                msg = 'Requested JSON parse failed.';
            } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                msg = 'Time out error.';
            } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                msg = 'Ajax request aborted.';
            } else {
                msg = 'Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText;
            }
            Materialize.toast(msg, 4000);
        },
    });
```

En mi caso eh usado MaterializeCss para que tenga un mejor juego en el toast. Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Gracias!! Me lo resolviste!

Comment: No es necesario devolver un json en php, valga la aclaración. Uno puede devolver lo que plasca, siempre y cuando uno sepa como leer el dato por el lado del cliente.